# Javascript -Paste from clipboard to specific cell in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I have a JS function that copies an image from a div onto a clipboard (only in IE) and pastes it into Excel. I would like to know how I can paste the contents of the clipboard into a specific cell in Excel. Here is the JS function code snippet I have. I would like to know how I can paste the clipboard contents into a specific cell

```
var imgObj = document.getElementById('exportimage');
imgObj.contentEditable = 'true';
var controlRange;
if (document.body.createControlRange) 
{
    controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
    controlRange.addElement(imgObj);
    controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
    var objExcel = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application");
    objExcel.visible = true;
    var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add;
    var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1);    
    objWorksheet.Paste;
 }
```

Copying to clipboard from div, and pasting it into Excel may not be a recommended approach but I would like to get this working for an internal (use only) application

Comment: Does this code currently paste the image into the first cell in the sheet? If so you probably have to select the cell you want to paste into and then invoke .Paste. I'm just guessing - I don't have IE or excel.

Comment: maybe: `objWorksheet.range('R2')` or `objWorksheet.cells('D2')` ?

Comment: Yes. This code does paste the image into the first cell in the sheet. I am able to assign a value by doing objWorksheet.range('R2').value='abc'; but I don't know how to paste into a specific cell.

Comment: You say the code pastes the image into the first cell but you don't know how to paste into a specific cell. Do you mean it pastes to that location? Are you sure it is IN the cell or located AT the cell?

Comment: You are right datatoo. The code pastes the image AT the cell and not IN the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you will achieve is pasting to the location where the cell is. You can't insert into the cell. There are other things you may want to do such as insert the image into a comment, or paste an image link, but actually placing the image in the cell isn't going to work.

The closest you can get is to define the Range("A1").Select  (or whatever location) and paste to that beginning point. You can also fine tune the location however, so depending on what you are trying to do you can offset from a cell range by specific amounts, if that is what you need.